# How to return multiple value with different data type from a single function in c

Tags: c, function, return-value

i want to return a char variable and two int variable to main function from the input() function so how can i do that

```
char Input(char ctgry, int cls, int day)
{
    
    do
    {
        printf("Category (G-Government, N-Non government) : ");
        scanf("%c", &ctgry);

        if (ctgry != 'G' && ctgry != 'N')
            printf("Invalid\n");
    } while (ctgry != 'G' && ctgry != 'N');
    
    do
    {
        printf("Ward Class: ");
        scanf("%d", &cls);
        if (cls != 1 && cls != 2 && cls != 3)
            printf("Invalid\n");
    } while (cls != 1 && cls != 2 && cls != 3);
    
    printf("No. of days: ");
    scanf("%d", &day);

    return;
}
```

Comment: How about passing the addresses of the variables aka call by reference?

Comment: egarding: `scanf("%c", &ctgry);` this will not (on any one execution) consume the trailing newline.  The result is this containing loop executing more than once with no usable results,,  Suggest: `scanf(" %c", &ctgry);`  Notice the space, which will consume any 'white space'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
char Input( char* ctgry, int* cls, int* day ) ;
```

Then for example the assignment of `cls` would be:

```
scanf( "%d", cls ) ;
```

i.e. remove the "address-of" `&` operator so the *caller's* variable is modified.

It is not clear what you intended to return (you defined it `char` but return nothing), but returning a single char via a `char* ctgry` is unusual and potentially misleading - it looks like a string might be returned.  I'd suggest:

```
char Input( int* cls, int* day)
{
    char category = 0 ;

    ...

    return category ;
}
```

Which you'd call:

```
int x, y ;
char cat = Input( &x, &y ) ;
```

---

As an aside, your input checking is unsafe, you do not check for example that `scanf()` succeeds in interpreting input.  For example if for `cls` the user types "ABC", no conversion will occur and the value of `cls` is undefined - the subsequent test may non-deterministically be either true or false regardless of the input validity:

```
    int converted = scanf( "%d", cls ) ;
    if( converted == 0  && cls < 1 && cls > 3 )
        printf("Invalid\n");
```

You need a validity check for `day` too - not for range but because the user may enter something that cannot match `%d` -although perhaps negative values might be invalid?

You might also avoid repeating the validity check expression in the while condition to avoid mismatching the tests and to reduce maintenance:

```
bool valid = false ;
do
{
    valid = scanf( "%d", cls ) != 0 && 
            cls > 0 && cls < 4 ;

    if( !valid ) printf( "Invalid\n" ) ;

} while( !valid ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

In C you can **only return one value**. So there is no way to return a char and two integers.

However, there are work arounds.

You can group the variables in a struct and return a struct value. Like:

```
struct retVal
{
    char a;
    int b;
    int c;
}

struct retVal foo(...)
{
    struct retVal result;
    ...
    result.a = some_value;
    result.b = some_value;
    result.c = some_value;
    return result;
}
```

and call it like:

```
struct retVal values = foo(...);
printf("Values after function call %c %d %d\n", values.a, values.b, values.c);
```

Alternatively, you can pass pointers to the two integers and then update them directly in the function.

Like:

```
char foo(int* i1, int* i2, ...)
{
    char result;
    ...
    result = some_value;
    *i1 = some_value;
    *i2 = some_value;
    return result;
}
```

and call it like:

```
int x;
int y;
char c = foo(&x, &y, ...);
printf("Values after function call %c %d %d\n", c, x, y);
```

Comment: currently we are not yet to use the struct according to my course so i can only make use of function and arrays to do this but im gonna go have a look at call by reference thing

Answer (score -1):

We can return more than one values from a function by using the method called “call by address”, or “call by reference”. In the invoker function, we will use two variables to store the results, and the function will take pointer type data. So we have to pass the address of the data.